# Convert cStringIO variable into file

Tags: python, xlrd, xlwt, cstringio

I have an Excel file created inside a cStringIO variable.

I need to open it and read it. But to open an excel file with the `xlrd` function `xlrd.open_workbook(excel_file_name)`, I need to call it by its file name. But in this case there is no file name because it is a cStrinIO variable that contains the representation of the Excel file.

How can I convert the cStringIO variable into a real excel file that I can open?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [xlrd.open_workbook()](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966#__init__.open_workbook-function) accepts file_contents argument as well, so maybe as follows?

```
xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=cstringio_var.getvalue())
```

Comment: Indeed. This is the right way for the original question. I'd like to keep my answer as a general workaround though :)

Comment: Thank you both Felix and Tommi! Both answers worked for me, but I ended up using Tommi's since it is the way the function is designed to be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile).

Example (not tested):

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
    f.write(your_cStringIO_variable.read())
    f.flush()
    something = xlrd.open_workbook(f.name)
```